# Could not establish site-to-site communication for apache nifi

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-nifi

I am working with two instances of nifi.

Instance-1: A secure nifi single node.

Instance-2: A secure 3-node nifi cluster on AWS.

My site to site settings have the below configurations:

Instance-1:

```
nifi.remote.input.host=<hostname running locally
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
```

Instance-2:

```
nifi.remote.input.host=<ec2 public fqdn>.compute.amazonaws.com
nifi.remote.input.secure=true
nifi.remote.input.socket.port=10443
nifi.remote.input.http.enabled=true
```

My remote processor group is in locally running nifi and I am trying to push a flowfile from local to AWS cluster. I am facing error as below:

[Error while trying to connect RPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g3DO.png)

Comment: This means there is some issue making the TLS/SSL connection.. how did you generate the keystores and truststores for your local and AWS NiFis? They would have to come from the same CA, or each truststore would have to trust the other's CA.

Comment: Each of the local and AWS nifi have different certs corresponding to their standalone servers. I have used nifi-toolkit for generating the standalone certs:
`/opt/nifi/nifi-toolkit-1.0.0/bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n 'localhost' -C 'CN=kylo, OU=NIFI' -o .` Here localhost and CN are replaced by corresponding hostnames and CN. 
How can I have each truststore to trust each other CA's?

Comment: If you ran the toolkit twice on different servers, then each time it created its own CA and self-signed the certs, so you could re-do the process and generate both certs from the same toolkit location this way they come from the same CA, alternatively you would need to get the public key of each CA added to each truststore https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/03/add-list-certficates-java-keystore.html

Comment: works! by having the same CA